# NodeJS - Find the line of unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, event-handling

I'm using an event handler to catch unhandled promise rejections, found on SO:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(error, promise) {
    console.error('UNHANDLED REJECTION - Promise: ', promise, ', Error: ', error, ').');
});
```

Since I'm using nodejs + express, it's tricky to print out line numbers for code statements. I have a customized console.log2 method for doing so, but I'm trying to accomplish the same with the rejection handler.

I've tried various caller/stack trace tricks with error stacks and such, but none of those methods correctly show what line the reject() statement is on.

*EDIT*

To clarify, the print out I get keeps showing the line number that the console.error statement above is on (thus same line everytime), then works backwards through the various promise library files/lines. It completely skips/misses the line that the reject() statement itself is on.

Comment: @JaromandaX - yes, .trace did not work either. Will clarify in question.

Comment: Did you just try code inspection to find where you're using `.then()` without a `.catch()`?  Might find more than just the one causing this event.

Comment: @jfriend00 - It's not about a specific rejection instance, I just want a generalized handler and I'd like it to include printing the caller line number.

Comment: I do not think the built-in promise library currently provides that capability.  With a proper configuration and the Bluebird promise library, you can get details that work like a stack trace for Bluebird promise rejections.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I'm trying to avoid dependencies if I can. It's not super essential, I was just hoping it could be done.

Answer (score 6):

depends very much on the libraries, I couldn't reproduce it, but I suggest you to try with this alternative:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', up => { throw up });
```

Should be more effective than just reporting promise and error, but maybe in your specific situation it may also not work properly. Just, give it a try!...